# My tables in mysql database have utf-8 collation still I am unable to import some names having Latin characters

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8

[image]The following is the output of this command:

> show create table persons;

```
CREATE TABLE `persons` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name_first` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '{search_person_txtP_mv}',
  `name_middle` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '{search_person_txtP_mv}',
  `name_last` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '{search_person_txtP_mv}',
  `name_unstructured` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'the entire string from {search_person_txtP_mv}, but only if the strong does not follow the "normal" logic',
  `added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name_first`,`name_middle`,`name_last`,`name_unstructured`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3795096 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='Persons are typically authors of documents but also users or editors are persons. '
```

I see that the name_first, name_last is equipped to handle utf8_unicode_ci. Yet I encounter java.lang.NullPointerException errors with the e.printStackTrace() pointing to either name_last, name_first when I try to import data.

The strange part is that the records that don't get inserted into the server db get inserted into the local db without any errors.

Name Insertion Code:

```
public Long addPersonToDbIfNotExists(JSONDocument document, Person author) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement stateAuthorExists = null;
        PreparedStatement stateInsertAuthor = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Long authorKey = null;
        int count = 1;   

        String queryAuthorExists = "SELECT " + constants.getPersonID() + " FROM " + constants.getPersons() + " WHERE "
                + constants.getFirstname() + (firstname == null ? " is null" : " = ? ") + " AND "
                + constants.getMiddlename() + (middlename == null ? " is null" : " = ? ") + " AND "
                + constants.getSurname() + (surname == null ? " is null" : " = ? ") + " AND "
                + constants.getUnstructured() + (unstructured == null ? " is null" : " = ? ");

        try {
            stateAuthorExists = conn.prepareStatement(queryAuthorExists, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

            // if not null insert true value for the corresponding ? (which is
            // represented by count)
            if (firstname != null)
                stateAuthorExists.setString(count++, firstname);

            if (middlename != null)
                stateAuthorExists.setString(count++, middlename);

            if (author.getFirstname() != null)
                stateAuthorExists.setString(count++, surname);

            if (unstructured != null)
                stateAuthorExists.setString(count++, unstructured);

            rs = stateAuthorExists.executeQuery();

            // if it is a new author not already present in the database
            if (!rs.next()) {
                ResultSet rs2 = null;

                String queryAuthor = "INSERT INTO " + constants.getPersons() + " (" + constants.getFirstname() + ", "
                        + constants.getMiddlename() + ", " + constants.getSurname() + ", " + constants.getUnstructured()
                        + ")" + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

                try {
                    stateInsertAuthor = conn.prepareStatement(queryAuthor, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

                    // handle null values and other preprocessing stuff
                    SetIfNull(document, stateInsertAuthor, author.getFirstname(), 1, "string",
                            constants.getFirstname());
                    SetIfNull(document, stateInsertAuthor, author.getMiddlename(), 2, "string",
                            constants.getMiddlename());
                    SetIfNull(document, stateInsertAuthor, author.getSurname(), 3, "string", constants.getSurname());
                    SetIfNull(document, stateInsertAuthor, author.getUnstructured(), 4, "string",
                            constants.getUnstructured());

                    stateInsertAuthor.executeUpdate();

                    // get the autogenerated key back
                    rs2 = stateInsertAuthor.getGeneratedKeys();
                    if (rs2.next())
                        authorKey = rs2.getLong(1);

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.out.println(document.getDocumentPath() + ": " + document.getIdentifier() + "SetIfNulladdPersonToDB");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw e;
                } finally {
                    rs.close();
                    rs2.close();
                    stateInsertAuthor.close();
                }
            } else

                authorKey = (long) rs.getInt(constants.getPersonID());
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            System.out.println(document.getDocumentPath() + ": " + document.getIdentifier() + "addPersonToDB1");
            throw sqle;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(document.getDocumentPath() + ": " + document.getIdentifier() + "addPersonToDB2");
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            try {
                stateAuthorExists.close();
                if (rs != null)
                    rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
        return authorKey;
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code that you are using.

Comment: This is a character set problem, not a collation problem. What line of code throws the NPE? You've shown us your validation code, but not the code that does the insert. Take a look at the `characterSetEncoding` parameter of your JDBC connection string; sometimes default settings differ between severs. Read this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html

Comment: @O.Jones Added the insertion code

Comment: @O.Jones would the link that you provided apply to tomcat server as well?

Comment: Yes, tomcat and the other servlet containers use JDBC connection strings.

Answer (score 1):

The connection needs to establish that the client bytes are latin1:  Add something like `?useUnicode=no&characterEncoding=LATIN1` to the JDBC URL.

If you continue to have problems please dump some incorrectly stored data in hex.